# " So much + adjective " vs " Very much + adjective "

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. I am very much happy.
> 2. I am so much happy.
> 3. I am happy very much.
> 4. I am happy so much.

Are all of the above sentences correct?

We use the number (1) and (3) every day. But I think the number (2) isn't correct because we can't use "so + much+ adjective ". On the other hand,  "so " is interchangeable with " very ". As per the rule,  The number (1) is supposed to be wrong. Please  give me the explanation in detail. I am so so confused.

Comment: [Related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150754/differences-between-very-and-very-much-as-adjective-modifiers) also for _so much_ see [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so)

Comment: Who says we use numbers 1) and 3) every day? I *never* say either, I just say "I'm really happy" or "I'm thrilled to bits" (can't remember the last time I said either though....) . Which ones have you heard the most frequently? Which ones sound "right" and "natural" to you? Why do you think this is so? Which ones did you invent on the spot? And, which ones did you find on a website, or in a grammar book? Please name your source!!

Answer (score 1):

None of them sound correct to this US English speaker.  [We only use *much* with comparative adjectives, not simple adjectives like *happy*.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers)  That is, you could say "much happier", but not "much happy".

The idiomatic way to say it is "I am so happy" or "I am very happy".  You're correct that *very* and *so* are interchangeable in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The only grammatically correct sentence is the first one–but it almost always requires a mood or state directed towards something. For example–"I am very much happy to meet you" or "I'm very much looking forward to your event." It sounds formal and intelligent so you won't find your average person using that structure but it is perfectly acceptable and will generally cause you to be perceived as serious and enthusiastic.

"So much" is never used to reflect on your own mood or state. It is usually used to emphasize a verb.

"I ran so much, yesterday."
"I love French music so much."

It is colloquial, so you wouldn't use it in a professional paper, but conversationally no native would bat an eye.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Please keep in mind an answer is no place for commentary on other answers. If you find other answers incorrect, just give the correct explanation. Keep on point in your own answer.